# foldr confusion

Tags: list, haskell, lambda

I execute this statement on the interpreter

```
foldr (\x (a, b) -> if x == '_' then (a+1, [((div a 3), (mod a 3))] ++ b) else (a, b)) (0, []) "_______OX"
```

I expected the output to be

```
(7,[(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2.0)])
```

however the output is

```
(7,[(2,0),(1,2),(1,1),(1,0),(0,2),(0,1),(0,0)])
```

what am I doing wrong. As far as I know, foldr starts from the last element of the list and my lambda function appends it to the beginning of the accumulator list. So I should get (0,0) as the first element. However, it's the opposite and I'm puzzled. :(

Also, a small question - How do I go about assigning tags for questions like these?

Comment: If `(0, 0)` was the first element *added* to the list, then it would be the last element *of* the list. Is that what you're confused about?

Comment: For better readbility, you can always replace `[a] ++ b` by `a:b` or `(a):b` (depending on the form of a, but in most cases it's just `a`). Furthermore, `((a),(b))` can **always** be written `(a, b)`

Comment: @pubby, yes. isn't the element that is read first ends becoming the last element in the final list?

Comment: By the way, thanks to laziness, the function you pass to `foldr` actually how much of the list needs to be consumed to produce a result. This means `foldr` is still working from left to right - it starts evaluating f for the head of the list before possibly recursing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's simplify this a bit, for better explanation:

```
foldr (\c (a,b) -> (a+1, a:b)) (0, []) "hi"
```

Foldr is defined as

```
foldr f a [] = a
foldr f a (x:xs) = f x (foldr f a xs)
```

Let us call the lambda function `g`
Hence, the trace of the expression above:

```
g 'h' (foldr g (0,[]) "i") 
g 'h' (g 'i' (foldr g (0,[]) ""))
g 'h' (g 'i' (0, []))
g 'h' (1, [0])
(2, [1,0])
```

Answer (score 2):

After 'X' you have

```
    (0,[])
```

After '0' you have

```
    (0,[])
```

After first '_' you have

```
    (1,[(0,0)])
```

After secont '_' you have

```
    (2,[(0,1),(0,0)]) -- you prepend in: [((div a 3), (mod a 3))] ++ b
```

After third '_' you have

```
    (3,[(O,2),(0,1),(0,0)])
```

...